# How to cast Transaction State to fooState which is a type of ContractState?

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

I am trying to write flow tests in which I need to put checks on input States which are already consumed. So I extracted `Stateref's` from transaction and got their data via `toStateandRef()` method by passing the `staterefs`. Then I ran a for loop to make a list of all `inputstates` to put `instanceOf foostate` checks on that but java fails to cast the contents of list to `fooState`.

> ERROR: Cannot Cast TransactionState to type fooState

```
        List<StateRef> txInputs = recordedTx.getTx().getInputs();
        List<TransactionState<ContractState>> inputsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (StateRef stateref :txInputs) {
            StateAndRef<ContractState> inputState = node.getServices().toStateAndRef(stateref);
        TransactionState<ContractState> individualinputStates = inputState.getState();
        inputsList.add(individualinputStates);
        }

        assert (inputsList.stream().filter(it -> it instanceOf fooState).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple do:
`List<fooState> inputsList = recordedTx.getTx().inputsOfType(fooState.class);`